# Condition not applied properly in quarterly lookup in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT (outbound.data_bas_year||outbound.data_bas_month) as year,
           EXTRACT(QUARTER from to_date(outbound.data_bas_year||outbound.data_bas_month, 'YYYYMM')) AS quarter,
           count(outbound.call_time) as col_1_0_ 
      FROM cfk_dashboard.if_outbnd_call_dtl outbound 
     WHERE outbound.data_bas_year||outbound.data_bas_month between '20210101' and '20211231' 
       AND outbound.conn_call_number = 1
  GROUP BY year,quarter
```

I wrote a query to look up January through December quarterly, but no data for January is aggregated.

In other words, only February and March are counted except for January in the first quarter.

However, if I change the condition start date from 20210101 to 20201231, I get the result I want.

Why?

Comment: Are you trying to compare `202101` to `20210101` as text? In which case the answer is fairly obvious. Some sample data would help to clarify the question.

Comment: `WHERE  to_date(outbound.data_bas_year||outbound.data_bas_month, 'YYYYMM') between '20210101'::date and '20211231'::date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `to_date` generates date for you, if you have not `day` value then default value of day will be -01.
But in your query after command `WHERE` you are used `outbound.data_bas_year||outbound.data_bas_month`, this is gets only 202101 and you compare this with 20211231 or with 20210101, this will not work correctly. For example, you can use `outbound.data_bas_year||outbound.data_bas_month||'01'` or `to_date(outbound.data_bas_year||outbound.data_bas_month, 'YYYYMM') between '20210101'::date and '20211231'::date`